# Going to the city during long layover at Warsaw Chopin Airport

Tags: layovers, uk-citizens, poland, warsaw

In a couple of days I'll be flying with LOT airline with a transfer in Warsaw Chopin Airport.  I have about 12 hours between my flights (as scheduled) - I am arriving at around 10 am and my next flight departs around 10:30 pm.

Having essentially a whole day, I'm planning to go into the city.  My luggage will be checked through (I verified with the airline), so I'll only have my small backpack with me - so much easier to deal with.  I don't need a visa as I'm a UK citizen. From previous experience, LOT doesn't give me the boarding pass for the second flight, so I'll need to get that in Warsaw - before going to the city, naturally.

Other than the usual "make sure to be back on time", is there anything specific I need to be aware of with my plan?

Please note that this question is *not* about what to do in Warsaw for a day (I already have an itinerary in mind) and *not* about how to get to the city and back (I did my research on that front, too).

Comment: Go to the loo before leaving the airport. It's annoying if you arrive in the city center and you have to start looking for a toilet ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a train station within walking distance of the terminal, if you're going to take the train into the city, but last time I was there it was not easy to find: the signage was not very clear, basically. If you start walking along the airport access road you've gone too far.

Other than this I think it is very simple and easy. WAW is a good airport.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a budget: 
24h city transportation ticket is really cheaper than buy short-tern tickets each time.
Check  foursquare, soup can be found in ~5zl, quite good lunch in 15zl

if not on budget - city taxi must have price displayed at the door, so you'll know what you'll have to pay before you get that car.

Check weather forecast - it's almost cold there right now. (+umbrella)